# smaller breakpoints always override larger breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Just want to know how to make the styles of the larger breakpoints not to be overridden by smaller breakpoints.

I tried below

`<Box mt={{ lg: 0, md: 2 }}></Box>`

but the styles generated for lg:0 was overridden by styles that generated by *md:2*.

I know it was affected by the order of the styles and want to know how to customise it.

sorry for my poor english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles are written out in the order of the properties in the object, so if you want the larger breakpoint to win, it needs to be last. In the example below, the two boxes look the same in a small window size, but in a large window size only the second Box changes to no longer be indented.

```
import React from "react";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Box ml={{ lg: 0, xs: 10 }}>margin-left {"{ lg: 0, xs: 10 }"}</Box>
      <Box ml={{ xs: 10, lg: 0 }}>margin-left {"{ xs: 10, lg: 0 }"}</Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Box property order]

Comment: Tank you for your response, I tried it which is in your post, but I didn't see that it is affected by the order of the breakpoints, I just wrote below, is there something wrong with it? mt={{ xs: 2, lg: 0 }}

Comment: Please share a sandbox reproducing your problem. The code in your comment looks fine. In my example the order makes a difference.

Comment: I've tried changing the orders of the 'lg' and 'xs', no matter what the order is, the margin-top of 'lg' always overridden by 'xs'

Comment: As I said, please share a sandbox that reproduces it.

Comment: It's my mistake, I checked the example code which you presented above and rechecked my code, I realized that I missed another prop width={lg:500} that I passed together with mt, I add xs:0 into it, then it worked as expected. Thank you very much for helping me solving the problem. : )